# hiren's will not boot on windows 8.1 preview pc

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I burned a hiren's boot disc (latest version, I might add) to recover the password from my windows 8.1 computer, I have the BIOS order right and I have legacy mode on. I start the computer up and it goes straight to windows, I then shift + restart > use a device > Internal CD/DVD Drive and I get a "Failed to boot error" (or something along those lines, I'm convinced HP wouldn't be that much of a b**** as to make the exact wording important) I have no idea what to do next.

**TL,DR:** Hiren's won't boot.

Thank you,
Lenny

**SPECS AS FOLLOWS:**

HP 2000 notebook
8 GB DDR3 RAM
Intel CORE i3 processor
64 bit OS as well as x64 based processor
Windows 8.1 Preview Build 9431
Hiren's BootCD 15.2
If you need more, it can be provided

Comment: Are you sure the disk is OK? Did you try re-burning it, or trying it in a different computer?

Answer (score 2):

Have you disabled [Secure Boot](http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-secure-boot-in-windows-8/2013/02/25)?